# Using Android Accelerometer via Unity3D Remote- Z axis want to measure in 180 degree plane, not 360

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, unityscript

first of all, I am total n00B at Unity and Android both, but I have gotten this to work...75% and want to get it to 100%.

I am using Unity3D to receive accelerometer data from my Android RazrM via Unity Remote. I am using this data to move through the game.

The Z axis on the phone is portrait view top to bottom, the Z axis in Unity3D is depth- in and out of the screen.

I am using the phone face up and when it is lying flat on the table, the first person controller does not move. When I tilt the phone forward from horizontal (0), I (as the first person controller) move forward. Which is great, but when I tilt the phone backwards from horizontal, I also move forward.

I believe this is because the Z axis measures in 360 degrees. So upside down, the phone will give me the accel value and the backwards movement that I want. Unfortunately, it is not possible for me to continually flip the phone. It must remain face up.

What can I do to know which quadrant the z axis is in? Is there a condition I can read? This phone does not have a gyroscope. My C# script is below. X axis makes the player go left and right, Z just forward, no backward.

```
public class Movement2 : MonoBehaviour {
public float moveX = Input.acceleration.x;
public float moveY = Input.acceleration.y;
public float moveZ = Input.acceleration.z;
public int zeroZFlag;   

void Update () {
    moveX = Input.acceleration.x * 1;
    moveY = 0;
    moveZ = (1+ (Input.acceleration.z)); //~0.036 when flat, moveZ stays positive
    transform.Translate (0, 0, 0);       // no movement when flat

    if (moveZ >= 0.055 && moveZ >= -0.1){
    transform.Translate(moveX, moveY, moveZ);       
    zeroZFlag = 1;  
   }
```

EDIT:
I figured out how to fix this, and am posting it in hopes that someone else will be helped by it.
I used a combination of the Y axis, which is negative in one direction and positive in the other, and the Z axis, which is positive all the time. 
Here is the code:

```
public class Movement2 : MonoBehaviour {
public float moveX = Input.acceleration.x;
public float moveY = Input.acceleration.y;
public float moveZ = Input.acceleration.z;
public short zeroZFlag;

void Update () {
    moveX = Input.acceleration.x * 1;
    moveY = Input.acceleration.y * 1;;
    //moveZ = (1-(Mathf.Abs(Input.acceleration.z * 1)));
    moveZ = (1+ (Input.acceleration.z)); //~0.036 when flat, moveZ stays positive
    transform.Translate (0, 0, 0);

    if (moveZ >= 0.055 && moveZ >= -0.1) { zeroZFlag = 1;                       
                    if (moveY >= 0) {
                    transform.Translate (moveX, 0, moveZ);
                    }
                    if (moveY < 0){
                    transform.Translate (moveX, 0, -moveZ);
                    }
     else {
     zeroZFlag = 0;  
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A more simple implementation could look like this.

```
rigidbody.AddForce (new Vector3(Input.acceleration.x, 0, -Input.acceleration.z));
```

Adding a RigidBody component and modifying the velocity by adding force is the preferred method.